# Listbox - initialize with saved value in PHP

Tags: php, listbox

How can I initialize a listbox using a value from a table in the database?
When I'm posting page without doing changes in listbox, application save first value of listbox to the table.

```
<?php 
   $cpquery = "Select distinct(operater) from operater where dept='$dept' order by operater"; 
   $cpresult = mysql_query($cpquery) or die(mysql_error()); 
?> 
<select name="operater" value="operater"> <!-- Drop down --> 

<?php 
   if($cpresult) { 
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cpresult)) { 
          echo '<option value="' .$row['operater']. '">'. $row['operater']. '</option>' ; 
       } 
   } 
   echo "<option value='operater' ></option>"; 
 echo "</select>"; <!-- end of block --> –
```

Comment: Can you give us *any* kind of code to work with here?

Comment: As I wrote I need in the listbox view first value what I seved in table before.


<!-- start of block -->
  <?php
  $cpquery = "Select distinct(operater) from operater where dept='$dept' order by operater";
  $cpresult = mysql_query($cpquery) or die(mysql_error());
  ?>

  <select name="operater" value="operater">
  <!-- Drop down -->
  <?php
  if($cpresult) 
  {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cpresult))
   {
   echo '<option value="' .$row['operater']. '">'. $row['operater']. '</option>'  ;
   }
  }
  echo "<option value='operater' ></option>";
  echo "</select>";
<!-- end of block -->

Comment: You mean when the values are updated into `<option>` with selected value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a hidden form input with the "fallback" value, so in PHP you could check if your listbox was changed. If it wasn't, you could use this hidden value.

But I'm not sure I understood your question.

Comment: Now is in table saved by listbox value operater='John';
When I am opening some page with listbox the first value is for example 'Charles', the second ='John'.